# Installing i3 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, software-installation, repository, i3-wm

I'm trying to install i3 desktop environment and I just can't figure out how. I'm following tutorial [here](https://i3wm.org/docs/repositories.html).
and I'm stuck on the line:

```
echo "deb http://debian.sur5r.net/i3/ $(grep '^DISTRIB_CODENAME=' /etc/lsb-release | cut -f2 -d=) universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sur5r-i3.list
```

My terminal says Permission denied

Comment: One edit: I added sudo before it and nothing

Comment: You should run the command as a root.

Comment: Did that and nothing

Comment: Even the command `dpkg -i ./keyring.deb` should be run as a root.
Switch to root user (`sudo su`) then start from the `dpkg` command.

Comment: Yes I know, that # says it should be done as root

Comment: i3 is available in the [Ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=i3), just `sudo apt install i3` should suffice.